# I want to do a calculation inside a select from specific data of the same column. Is this possible?

Tags: sql, teradata, alation

I want to do a SUM calculation who calls multiple times my 'Q' and `QBUYERS` column, but within different rows
[this is my table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KdQB.png)

```
group   type   Q     QBUYERS
GROUP1  sent   300   200 
GROUP2  shown  400   100
GROUP3  sent   200   150`
```

And this is what I'm trying to do:

```sql
SELECT 
  notification_batch_id AS group,
  (secondrow) QBUYERS AS PAYERS_EXPOSED,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN (firstrow)Q <> 0 AND (secondrow)Q <> 0 AND (thirdrow)Q <> 0 
        THEN (
          (
            ((firstrow)QBUYERS / (firstrow)Q) - 
            ((thirdrow)QBUYERS / (thirdrow)Q) 
          ) / ((secondrow)Q / (firstrow)Q) 
        ) 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS CVR_INCREMENTAL FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY group;
```

Basically doing calculations between my numeric values and then grouping my results. But I don't know how to 'invoke' my 300, 400, 200 etc without selecting the entire column.

I also tried this:

```sql
SELECT 
  b.QBUYERS AS PAYERS_EXPOSED,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN a.Q <> 0 AND b.Q <> 0 AND c.Q <> 0 
        THEN (((a.QBUYERS / a.Q) - (c.QBUYERS / c.Q)) / (b.Q/a.Q)) 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS CVR_INCREMENTAL
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM BASE_FIRST a
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM BASE_SECOND b
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM BASE_THIRD c
) AS mytable
```

BASE_FIRST being:

```
group   type  Q    QBUYERS
GROUP1  sent  300  200`
```

BASE_SECOND being:

```
group   type  Q    QBUYERS
GROUP2  sent  400  100`
```

and so on...
but it didnt work.

Is this possible to do on TERADATA ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I imagine what you're trying to do is possible, but you'll need to give us a lot more info.  Sample data, desired results, how you define first, second, third rows.  Please put your data as tables in your post, not pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I edited my post

Comment: How are *1st/2nd/3rd row* defined? They must be either sorted or based on existing data, e.g. *group GROUP2 = secondrow*?

Comment: They are grouped by 'group' and 'type'

Comment: *They are grouped by 'group' and 'type'* But how is 1st/2nd/3rd determined?

Comment: *They are grouped by 'group' and 'type'* But how do you determine those groups, why is `GROUP2  shown` the 2nd group?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I follow your logic here, but if you want to run a query that matches only this specific case you describe, then your second query is pretty close.

Just modify it slightly to use `JOIN`s instead of `UNION`s.  That way you'll end up with single row where you can compare the values in your `SUM()` instead of multiple rows:

```sql
SELECT 
  b.QBUYERS AS PAYERS_EXPOSED,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN a.Q <> 0 AND b.Q <> 0 AND c.Q <> 0 
        THEN (
          (
            (a.QBUYERS / a.Q) - 
            (c.QBUYERS / c.Q) 
          ) / (b.Q / a.Q) 
        ) 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS CVR_INCREMENTAL 
FROM MYTABLE a
INNER JOIN MYTABLE b ON b.group = 'GROUP2'
INNER JOIN MYTABLE c ON c.group = 'GROUP3'
WHERE a.group = 'GROUP1'
```

This assumes that there are three only rows in your table -- one each for `GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3`.

If you want to handle a different, more complex scenario, please update the question with this info.

Comment: This almost works!! Thanks!! I end up with one row table but
I'm getting the error: invalid calculation: division by zero.
I don't even have zeros on the table

Comment: I'm guessing one of `a.Q, b.Q, c.Q` values in your query is NULL.  Is that the case?  If so, how do you want to handle that?  You could always put a `COALESCE` around the whole `THEN` expression and have it return a default value if this happens.